# populate Table from database(msaccess) to HTML Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my UI side I have a grid view like so:

Default.aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Then I am doing this my code runs but nothing comes up on the page:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(); //Creating a db object
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mydb.mdb";  
  try{
       connection.Open();
       OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
       command.Connection = connection; 
       string query ="Select * From events";
       command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;                               
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //error
    }
```

Msaccess Database:

```
|ID  |Date |Name    |Location      |age    |desc    | <--table header
|01  |2 dec|TestName| TestLocation |testAge|testDesc| <--table data
```

I want my **output** to look something like this:

```
|Date |Name    |Location      |age    |desc    |
|2 dec|TestName| TestLocation |testAge|testDesc|
```

Comment: First thing first, do not write plain SQL query `Select * From events`

Comment: @Div That's fine to do since he's not specifying any parameters, I mean you can't parameterize a table name. I don't see this as a SQL injection threat, am I wrong?

Comment: i also dont think it can be considered a sql injection threat but i could be wrong

Comment: You need to define your grid or make sure that it has AutoGenerateColumns = true.

Comment: it is already true

Comment: You need to write an extra line of code `GridView1.DataBind();` after `GridView1.DataSource = dt;`.

Comment: GridView1.DataBind(); worked for me thanks